# JSON Injection fix for jackson

Tags: java, json, rest, security

My static scan is giving a vulnerability saying I am writing unvalidated input into JSON. It advises that all serialization to JSON is performed using a safe serialization function that delimits untrusted data within single or double quotes and escapes any special characters.

Any idea how best to do that? I have checked the usual ESAPI classes and StringUtils methods but there's nothing much for Json. The http response is coming from within the company BTW. I cannot really find much in the way of discussion or solutions on this topic even.

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
objectMapper.readValue(entity.getContent(), MyObj.class);
```

Comment: Any solution for Jackson json injection?

Answer (score 0):

- This is probably a concern about the untrusted data pasted into JSON jumping out of its value context and proceeding to add or shadow other attributes of the object.

  https://vulncat.fortify.com/en/weakness?kingdom=Input+Validation+and+Representation&q=json%20injection
- The recent vulnerability of deserializing untrusted JSON objects using Jackson may open a respective way to abuse a potential Jackson consumer (further down the data flow) by injecting the unexpected class name into JSON (my own untested idea),

  https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2389
- If the JSON output is further pasted into HTML/javascript as a javascript object literal, certainly, injecting a closing tag for the object and malicious javascript will do wonders.
- If the JSON output is pasted into HTML as a string literal, it's possible to escape the context and trick a simple encoder by inecting a closing script tag `</script>`.  Browsers are required to drop out of the script tag context on seeing the closing tag anywhere past the opening tag, even inside a string literal.